# Does Melee Training affect the secondary attack of Riposte Strike?

Tags: dnd-4e, optimization, feats, rogue

Melee Training Feat from Heroes of the Fallen Lands, say you can sub another Ability mod for your melee attack bonus and half that Ability mod for damage bonus. PC chooses Dexterity.

Riposte has, If the target attacks you before the start of your next turn, you make your
riposte against the target as an immediate interrupt: a Strength vs. AC attack that deals 1[W] + Strength modifier damage.

If PC has both feat and At-will doesn't the interrupting attack now goes as Dexterity vs. AC. Attack deals 1[W] + 1/2 Dexterity mod?

Answer (score 8):

**No.**

The Melee Training feats modify your melee *basic* attacks only. The rogue's Riposte Strike power explicitly says to make a strength attack versus AC that does 1W+str damage. If it said to make an MBA then Melee Training would convert it to whatever ability modifier you want, but it doesn't.

It's explicitly designed that way to keep non-strength rogues from stealing all the strength rogues' toys.

Comment: they are rogues, they would do it.